# Powering MCU and LCD screen

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb-design, embedded, best-practice

I’m using a 7805CT to regulate power for an Atmega328p for a project with an LCD screen. At first I was planning on having the LCD screen connected to the output of the regulator as well until I noticed that the output of the regulator drops to ~3.3 V when the LCD is connected. **Is this normal? Should the voltage of the LCD come straight from the 5 V power supply I’m using? Is there a place to find rules of thumb for powering peripherals off Embedded projects?** The LCD is a 4 row LCD I found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GPUMP9C).
I am connecting it such that the GND of the IIC interface is connected to the negative terminal of the power supply which is also connected to the common terminal of the regulator (middle pin), and the Vcc (of the IIC interface) is connected to the output terminal of the regulator which *should* be 5 V.
The input of the regulator is coming from a bench top power supply set to 5 V and everything is on a breadboard. Once the PCB board is designed to house connections to MCU and a set of buttons, it is intended to be connected to a 5 V power supply such as this one [here](https://smile.amazon.com/Aiposen-Transformer-Security-Computer-Project/dp/B01B1QKLPA/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1P0BEMAYW2MXL&keywords=5V+power+supply&qid=1662618560&sprefix=5v+power+supply%2Caps%2C218&sr=8-5) .

[image: front view of the prototype]

Comment: LCDs often have a higher voltage for contrast control. In addition to other requirements they may have. This isn't an answer to one of your other questions, but it may still be a problem depending on what's included in your LCD screen, itself. It may or may not already include a charge pump of some kind. And no, I don't know of a place, per se, that's a one-stop shop for all knowledge embedded/peripheral.

Comment: Answering that requires knowledge of what LCD you are using and how you are connecting it. Please provide detailed info what you connected and how. You might simply be using or connecting the LCD wrong, but currently we don't know how you connect it. Does the LCD have a manual or data sheet?

Comment: Also please describe where the input to the regulator is coming from.

Comment: edited the original post above

Comment: Ye olde 7805 should have some 330nF on the input and 100nF on the output. I only see one cap on the picture. Additionally you'll want decoupling caps close to every IC supply pin. Breadboard = EMC nightmare even without those. They are not really suitable for learning, or for anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Feeding in 5V to a 5V regulator is wrong and it will not output 5V.

A 5V regulator requires more than 5V in, around 7-8 volts, for it to make 5V output.

Comment: Is that the only issue?

Comment: How would I know? Does it work when you fix the issue you asked about?

Comment: @sabz if you plan to use a good external power supply at 5V, consider to not use a 7805 - it will waste energy. But instead add some protection and filter.